# Is there a "Long" Up Down Arrow?

Tags: symbols, arrows

The traditional `\Updownarrow` is short. However, I want a "long" `\Updownarrow`. Does it exist? What package should I seek?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the `\Updownarrow` symbol can be increased (almost) arbitrarily by placing it inside a pair of `\left...\right` directives. Moreover, as @egreg points out in  a comment, `\big\Updownarrow` through `\Bigg\Updownarrown` is available as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\Updownarrow$
$\displaystyle\left\Updownarrow\vphantom{\int}\right.$
$\displaystyle\left\Updownarrow\vphantom{\int_A^B}\right.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\big` and so on.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've amended my answer to include your observation.

Comment: Wow, cool! I originally thought that `\big`-family will not work before posting, since I guess those will enlarge the symbol "equal-ratio-ly" (leading a stick stem).